# files from the array are not loaded

Tags: php, laravel

I store files in the laravel storage and download them by name

in this case, the file is being downloaded

```
 <a href="../downloads/exaA18D.jpg"><button class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>
```

but not here

```
 <a href="../downloads/{{ $files[$i] }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>
```

Why is this happening?
because the array contains the same value

Comment: Did you get any error message? what is the output of `$files[$i]`?